# Regex pattern in java fails but works fine otherwise

Tags: java, regex

I've implemented quite a complicated [pattern](http://regexr.com/3bujl)` to match all occurences of ship set number. It works perfectly fine with global case insensitive comparison.

I use the following code to implement the same thing in Java but it doesn't match. Should Java regex be implemented differently?

```
int i = 0;
while (i < elementsArray.size()) {
    System.out.println("List element:"+elementsArray.get(i));
    String theRegex = "(?i)(([Ss]{2}|Ship\\s*(set))\\s*(\\#|Number|No\\.)?\\s*([:=\\-\\n\\'\\s])?\\s*\\d+\\s*(\\W*\\d+\\W?\\s*(to|and)?|(to|and)\\s*\\d+)*)";
    if (elementsArray.get(i).matches(theRegex)) {
        System.out.println("RESULT:");
        String shipsets = "";
        String thePattern = "(?i)(([Ss]{2}|Ship\\s*(set))\\s*(\\#|Number|No\\.)?\\s*([:=\\-\\n\\'\\s])?\\s*\\d+\\s*(\\W*\\d+\\W?\\s*(to|and)?|(to|and)\\s*\\d+)*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(thePattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(elementsArray.get(i));

        if (matcher.find()) {
            shipsets = matcher.group(0);
        }

        System.out.println("text==========" + shipsets);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: I could swear that I just saw this question 5 minutes ago...

Comment: My general advice to you would be to take the regex apart, and debug it piece by piece until either the whole thing works or you find the bug.

Comment: complicated pattern` isn't giving the explanation that what u want to do using this pattern???

Comment: @PankajSaboo can use the link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your problems are coused by:

1. usage of `matches()` in `if(elementsArray.get(i).matches(theRegex))` - `matches()` will return
   `true` only if whole string match to regex, so it will succeed in
   many cases from your example, but it will fail with:
   `SS#1,SS#5,SS#6`, `SS1, SS2, SS3, SS4`, etc. You can simulate this
   situation by adding `^` at beginning and `$` at the end of regex.
   Check how it match [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/jV3nB2/1). So it would be better solution, to use
   `matcher.find()` instead of `String.matches()`, like in Tim
   Biegeleisen answer.
2. usage of `if(matcher.find())` instead of `while(matcher.find())` - in
   some of strings you want to retrieve more than one result, so you
   should use `matcher.find()` multiple times, to get all of them.
   However `if` will act only once, so you will get only first matched
   fragment from given string. To retrieve all, use loop, as `matcher.find()` will return `false` when it will not find next match in given String, and will end loop

[Check this out](https://ideone.com/xC6LLa). This is Tim Biegeleisen solution with small change (`while`, instead of `if`).

Comment: You are correct it was because of `matches` in the if statement. Thanks

Comment: That is very observant to use the `while` loop instead of `if`, saved all kinds of matches. Great analysis!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplification of your code which *should* work, assuming that your regex be working correctly in Java.  From my preliminary investigations, it does seem to match many of the use cases in your link.  You don't need to use `String.matches()` because you already are using a `Matcher` which will check whether or not you have a match.

```
List<String> elementsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
elementsArray.add("Shipset Number 323");
elementsArray.add("meh");
elementsArray.add("SS NO. : 34");
elementsArray.add("Mary had a little lamb");
elementsArray.add("Ship Set #2, #33 to #4.");

for (int i=0; i < elementsArray.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println("List element:"+elementsArray.get(i));
        String shipsets = "";
        String thePattern = "(?i)(([Ss]{2}|Ship\\s*(set))\\s*(\\#|Number|No\\.)?\\s*([:=\\-\\n\\'\\s])?\\s*\\d+\\s*(\\W*\\d+\\W?\\s*(to|and)?|(to|and)\\s*\\d+)*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(thePattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(elementsArray.get(i));

        if (matcher.find()) {
            shipsets = matcher.group(0);
            System.out.println("Found a match at element " + i + ": " + shipsets);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see in the output below, that the three ship test strings all matched, and the controls `"meh"` and `"Mary had a little lamb"` did not match.

**Output:**

```
List element:Shipset Number 323
Found a match at element 0: Shipset Number 323
List element:meh
List element:SS NO. : 34
Found a match at element 2: SS NO. : 34
List element:Mary had a little lamb
List element:Ship Set #2, #33 to #4.
Found a match at element 4: Ship Set #2, #33 to #4.
```

Comment: Big thanks to whoever just upvoted me.  His question is actually legitimate, but was presented badly at first, so it got ignored by everyone.